# create query to get all components that refer to all selected ids of substances

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your help to create some oracle SQL query, let's first see the design of my tables

```
Component table has two cols id(pk) and name

Substance table has two cols id(pk) and name
```

The Component consists of many substances so I created a third table 
Comp_Subs has two cols `comp_id(fk to Component)` and `sub_id(fk to substance)` and the cols together are unique.

Given some ids of substances, Create a query to get all components that have all the given substances

[Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaBGK.png)

Example: given these ids of substances 1, 2, 3 create a query that will retrieve all Comps that have all the selected substances.

input : 1,2,3

Output will one column contains the result like that

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otIDc.png)

The result of the given example should return comp1 and comp2 
Because comp1 contains substances 1, 2 and 3
And comp2 also contains 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Can you please format your question better with all 3 tables schemas
? Also, please paste Sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4583f/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Comp_Sub ( comp_id, sub_id ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 7 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT comp_id
FROM   comp_sub
WHERE  sub_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
GROUP BY comp_id
HAVING COUNT( sub_id ) = 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4583f/1/0)**:

```
| COMP_ID |
|---------|
|       1 |
|       2 |
```

If you want names then join the results to the `Component` table.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the output by selecting the `comp_subs` records with the desired `sub_id` grouped by `comp_id`, like so:

```
select comp_id
from comp_subs
where subs_id in (1,2,3)
group by comp_id;
```

Comment: This gives the wrong results as there is a `comp_id=3, sub_id=1` pair that will be matched in your sub-query.

Comment: @MT0 I recently edited my answer because the OP added some desired output. But I guess, my answer is still not right because I overlooked his requirement: "all Comps that have all the selected substances."